# How do I decode an Avro message in Python?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, avro, fastavro

I am having trouble decoding an Avro message in Python (3.6.11). I have tried both the `avro` and `fastavro` packages. So I think that the problem may be that I'm providing the bytes incorrectly.

Using [avro](https://repl.it/repls/HarshBelovedDebugger#main.py):

```
from avro.io import DatumReader, BinaryDecoder
import avro.schema
from io import BytesIO

schema = avro.schema.parse("""
    {
        "type": "record",
        "name": "User",
        "namespace": "example.avro",
        "fields": [
            {
                "name": "name",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "favorite_number",
                "type": [
                    "int",
                    "null"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "favorite_color",
                "type": [
                    "string",
                    "null"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
""")

rb = BytesIO(b'{"name": "Alyssa", "favorite_number": 256}')
decoder = BinaryDecoder(rb)
reader = DatumReader(schema)
msg = reader.read(decoder)
print(msg)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 36, in <module>
    msg = reader.read(decoder)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/avro/io.py", line 626, in read
    return self.read_data(self.writers_schema, self.readers_schema, decoder)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/avro/io.py", line 698, in read_data
    return self.read_record(writers_schema, readers_schema, decoder)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/avro/io.py", line 898, in read_record
    field_val = self.read_data(field.type, readers_field.type, decoder)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/avro/io.py", line 638, in read_data
    return self.read_union(writers_schema, readers_schema, decoder)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/avro/io.py", line 854, in read_union
    index_of_schema = int(decoder.read_long())
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/avro/io.py", line 240, in read_long
    b = ord(self.read(1))
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 0 found
```

Use [fastavro](https://repl.it/repls/EnchantedRapidNamebinding#main.py):

```
from fastavro import schemaless_reader, parse_schema
from io import BytesIO

schema = parse_schema(
    {
        "type": "record",
        "name": "User",
        "namespace": "example.avro",
        "fields": [
            {
                "name": "name",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "favorite_number",
                "type": [
                    "int",
                    "null"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "favorite_color",
                "type": [
                    "string",
                    "null"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
)

rb = BytesIO(b'{"name": "Alyssa", "favorite_number": 256}')
msg = schemaless_reader(rb, schema)
print(msg)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 33, in <module>
    msg = schemaless_reader(rb, schema)
  File "fastavro/_read.pyx", line 969, in fastavro._read.schemaless_reader
  File "fastavro/_read.pyx", line 981, in fastavro._read.schemaless_reader
  File "fastavro/_read.pyx", line 652, in fastavro._read._read_data
  File "fastavro/_read.pyx", line 510, in fastavro._read.read_record
  File "fastavro/_read.pyx", line 644, in fastavro._read._read_data
  File "fastavro/_read.pyx", line 429, in fastavro._read.read_union
  File "fastavro/_read.pyx", line 200, in fastavro._read.read_long
StopIteration
```

I don't know if the message that I'm encoding is malformed or if the problem is with the encoding itself. Any suggestions?

Comment: aren't you supposed to read avro files? You are currently trying to read a data which is not in avro format. You can write the content to avro file and then read again

Comment: I'm using kafka-python to consume from a topic. But I keep running into issues decoding the message. I was trying to isolate the decoding issues, but you're probably right that I can't do it this way. When I write to a buffer using either library, I am able to decode it. The issue may actually be in my kafka-python consumer then, or even the messages that are being produced on my topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll speak to fastavro since that is what I know best.

Your `rb` variable should be the avro binary you are trying to read (not the data). To get an example of what this binary is, you could do a write:

```py
rb = BytesIO()
schemaless_writer(rb, schema, {"name": "Alyssa", "favorite_number": 256})
rb.getvalue()  # b'\x0cAlyssa\x00\x80\x04\x02'
```

Then you could do what you are trying to and read that resulting binary:

```py
rb = BytesIO(b'\x0cAlyssa\x00\x80\x04\x02')
data = schemaless_reader(rb, schema)
# {'name': 'Alyssa', 'favorite_number': 256, 'favorite_color': None}
```

Comment: Not sure where my head was at. I was using AKHQ and producing messages on a Kafka topic. I mistakenly thought AKHQ was encoding the message to Avro using the schema in the registry. I realized that wasn’t happening once I read the comment on my question. I added a producer that does just what you described with the schemaless_writer and problem solved.